# jQuery: target first class of div when it has a class of 'this'

Tags: jquery

```
<ul id="navigation">
     <li class="this">example1</li>
     <li>example2</li>
     <li>example3</li>
</ul>
```

If I want to target the first child of #navigation (`<li class="this">example1</li>`) when it has a class of 'this' and add another class, how would I do that with jQuery?

Something like this? `jQuery("#navigation:first-child.this").addClass("corner");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#navigation li:first-child.this").addClass("yournewclass");
```

See a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/z3rFU/)

Answer (score 1):

An alternate method which doesn't use a chained selector (and so is in theory faster)

```
$('#navigation').children().first().filter('.this').addClass('corner');
```

which *should* also make the desiried logic obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Use this selector

```
$("#navigation .this:first").addClass("corner");
```

This selector means:  Select the first match from #navigation that has a class named "this".

Comment: I only want to add it to the first item if it has a class of 'this'. Wouldn't that code add it to all items if they have a class of 'this'?

Answer (score 0):

I found that this code works: `$("#navigation li:first-child.this").addClass("corner");`